# Navbar logo won't appear (bootstrap/django)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

Hello I'm trying to add a logo to my navbar but it won't show up. I've looked at other's questions on this matter but I still can't make it show up.
I'm not sure whether the problem is with my code or my image.
I have added the image into the same directory as my code.

[image]

My code is as below

```css
.navbar li a {
  background-image: "/app/static/app/images/logoa.png";
}

.search {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: fit-content;
  border: 0px;
  /*border added to visualise collision box*/
}

.search-bar {
  display: none;
}

.search-icon {
  width: fit-content;
  border: 0px;
  /*border added to visualise collision box*/
}

.search-icon:hover+.search-bar {
  display: block;
}

.search-bar:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <img src="/app/templates/logoa.png" alt="computer display with dna in it" width="30" height="24" class="d-inline-block align-text-top">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                  </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
      <div class="navbar-nav">
        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">homepage</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">form</a>
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">workflow</a>
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">tools</a>
      </div>
      <ul class="search">
        <li class="search-icon"><i class="fas fa-search" style="position:absolute; right:10px;"></i></li>
        <li class="search-bar" style="position:absolute; right:10px;"><input placeholder="enter search" action=""></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

edit;;
if i try to follow the path i set in the code it leads me to the image (in visual studio code)
but it can't find it in the browser console

> help.png:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a >status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Are you sure there is no typo in "logoa.png"?

Comment: remove first slash `/` most of the time this comes to be the problem when using short path write is like this : `app/static/app/images/logoa.png`

Comment: What does your browser console reveal? If you have a missing file, that will be reported (which means your path is wrong). Or is the image loaded but not shown? Or is it shown but not visible (e.g. moved off screen or zero size)? Basically, please tell us what "it won't show up" actually means. When odd things happen, your browser's Inspector is a great tool (right-click and choose "Inspect element").

Comment: Also, is the pathing to your image correct. Where is your image located relative to your HTML page? Do you need to back-up using ../ at the beginning of the link so that /app/templates can be found?

Comment: @Zain yes i have two images logo.png and logoa.png

Comment: @Rana thank you for your suggestion! i tried that and nothing changed unfortunately :/

Comment: @JohnP just checked the console and it says  "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) " but i've provided it a full path and when i click on it in the browser application it shows all the images i have in a list including logoa but it will preview all of them except logoa

Comment: @CuteCodeRob 'templates' is the same directory as my html code. i thought it might be able to find it easier if i put them in the same directory

Comment: @stelaa If you are getting a 404 then something is wrong about your path. When you say "when I click on it...", what do you mean? The path is `/app/templates/logoa.png` in your code above, which suggests you're using some framework to build your app. Are you sure this path is the path to the output file in your built project? Because if you can load the file in your browser using a particular path, that path ought to work on your page, too. (As long as it really is *identical*.)

Comment: The path to the image in your HTML above suggests that you have a HTML page and then in the same location with the HTML page is a folder called App, inside the App folder is a folder called Templates. Inside that folder should be your image. Just double check it. Is the app folder located in the same place as your HTML page? If so just remove the very first /

Comment: Also, is it possible that there's a permission problem on the logo file? (The fact you can see some files inn the founder but not all of them is suggestive.) And double (treble) check that the path that works is *exactly* the same one you're using on the html page.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. What worked for me was removing the extension that I was using for the image (.svg) and let Visual Studio code suggest/pick the right extension/path (.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. In the .html page, instead of: `<img src="/app/templates/logoa.png"` try rendering the image with this path instead: `<img src="{% static 'app/templates/logoa.png' %}"` This syntax is more "Django friendly". Hope this helps.